# Debian boot fails after forced shutdown

Tags: debian, boot, usb

I was accessing my Android data(files) through Virtualbox(windows), it was very very slow, I forced shutdown, but now my encrypted debian won't start anymore, I'm not a pro, if someone have an idea of what is the source of the problem please send me a message

[image: errorMsg1]

[image: errorMsg2]

- .device

Comment: Wow, that's a really dirty screen... time to clean it, I'd say!

Comment: @Michael Kjörling ahah I agree

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it, this might not be due to the failed shutdown.  To attempt continuing without the USB device working:

1. Edit options for the current boot (e.g. press the shift key at the grub menu to stop the countdown, and follow onscreen instructions); add `init=/bin/bash` to the line which lists linux kernel options like `root=`, and then boot the system.  Wait for the scrolling to stop.  Hit enter, and you should see a bash command prompt ending in `#`.
2. `mount / -o remount,rw`
3. `vi /etc/fstab`  # vi, text editor of the ancients, which can be assumed to exist
4. Use `j` / `k` keys to scroll up/down to the line containing `/mnt/usb-...`.
5. `i` key to enter insert mode
6. Insert character `#`, at the start of the line to disable it.
7. `Esc` key to return to `vi` command mode.
8. `:wq` to Write changes and Quit.
9. `poweroff -f`

Comment: @sourcejedi Thanks a lot, I don't have enough free space to save grrrr, will by a usb key tomorrow to fix this, thanks again !!! @ Michael Kjörling thanks for your help also :)